# Drupal customise block views_embed_view

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

Please help me find the block file from which the output has been retrieved  below ?

`$output = views_embed_view('shop_mainhome', 'block_1', '');`

I want to add some new elements to the block & style them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the "View" content by going to yoursite/admin/structure/views and click on the "shop_mainhome" view and edit it.. to style it you can create a template file in your theme .. you need to find your template file name from the view itself by clicking ->advanced->Theme:Information. you will see some template file suggestions like" **views-view--test--page.tpl.php**" . that you can use to change the view html output. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Good answer, but please format your answer better for easier readability. Use capitals, use backticks to format code and use paragraphs. Thanks.